# Sharepoint Online - CAML query in CSOM Script issue with date range

Tags: date-range, csom, caml, content-query-web-part

I need to run in a javascript webpart (CSOM) a CAML query between 2 dates.

CAML query returns nothing if I define date criteria with correct format ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ).

```
var cQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
var camlXML = "<View><Query><Where><And>"
    +"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'><UserID/></Value></Eq>"
    +"<Geq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>2022-05-18T01:00:00Z</Value></Geq>"
    +"<Leq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>2022-08-24T01:00:00Z</Value></Leq>"
    +"</And></Where></Query></View>";
        
/* camlXML = "<View><Query><Where>"
    +"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'><UserID/></Value></Eq>"
    +"</Where></Query></View>"; */ This query works perfectly...
    
cQuery.set_viewXml(camlXML);
oListItems = oList.getItems(cQuery);
```

I'va also tried to define only date without time (ie 2022-05-18) but same issue.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your query looks fine. Does the query return any result if you set IncludeTimeValue='True'?

Comment: Whatever IncludeTimeValue flag, behavior IS the same. No results.